During WWII, did the Allies know about the location and significance of the Wolf's Lair? If so, why did they not attack it?
The German Wikipedia article about this Eastern Front military headquarters states that

Adolf Hitler spent more time at the Wolf's Lair than anywhere else during World War II: over 800 days.

and that

In total, about 100 different objects and buildings were built in the area between 1940 and 1944.

The English Wikipedia article:

At its peak, over 2,000 people lived and worked at the Wolf's Lair

Seemingly making it a difficult to overlook (and miss) target.

Hitler's bunker had become the largest, "a positive fortress" containing "a maze of passages, rooms and halls." Junge wrote, "We had air-raid warnings every day" in the period between the 20 July assassination attempt and Hitler's final departure from the Wolfsschanze in November 1944, "but there was never more than a single aircraft circling over the forest, and no bombs were dropped. All the same, Hitler took the danger very seriously, and thought all these reconnaissance flights were in preparation for the big raid he was expecting."


No air attack ever came. It has never been revealed whether the Western Allies knew of the Wolfsschanze's location and importance. The Soviet Union was unaware of both the location and the scale of the complex until the site was uncovered by its forces during their advance towards Berlin in early 1945.

Given these (likely) reconnaissance flights, and the fact that British-American intelligence managed to intercept even the highest level Nazi communications, would they not know of this location?
And if they did, why did they not attack it?

"It has never been revealed whether the Western Allies knew of the Wolfsschanze's location and importance." - this seems to answer your question.

@SPavel I would not rely on Wikipedia to give me a definitive answer, perhaps there are other sources

@2080 do you have any reason to believe that wikipedia and its source (Beevor, Antony (1999) Stalingrad: The Fateful Siege: 1942–1943. New York: Penguin Books. ISBN 9780140284584) are wrong?

What would be the point of such a bombing mission deep into Germany, deeper than almost all others? Would that mission be more important than the many other targets available?

@DanM No, and I can't judge the quality of the source. However, relying only on one seems to be foolish

Why would they attack it? What would be the point? To kill Hitler? Was Hitler such a strategic genius that, deprived of his leadership, the Wehrmacht would be more difficult to defeat?

@bof, self-quoting my comment to totalMongot's answer : "to disorganize the German's chain of command, to force the Germans to place more anti-aircraft capabilities in that area (thus removing them from more strategic locations), to exacerbate Hitler's paranoia to induce him to take irrational decisions detrimental to Germany's war effort, to lower German High Command's morale"

Sorry, but anybody who has been to the 'Wolfschanze' (as I was in Feburary 1975) will tell you: it is the middle of nowhere, deep inside a forest. The area is filled with highly fortified 'buildings' (that in reality are bunkers). After WW2 they attempted to destroy them, but did not suceed. Hitler survived a bomb emploding within one of these fortified 'buildings'. The notion that before 1945 that an airplane would fly the 1.111 miles (by road accourding to google maps) from London and destroy all (or some) of those buidings is exceedingly naive.

Please assume that there were higher priorities at that time that were more worthy of attention and likelihood of success.

I think you are misleading yourself about how strategic air bombing worked at the time of WWII. Over Germany, because of the necessity to fly far, to avoid anti-aircraft guns, and to defend against fighters, American day bombers had to adopt high-altitude formations. They had difficulty to follow a precise navigation over the thousand kilometer needed to reach the Ruhr from the United Kingdom, and it would have been even more difficult to reach the Wolf's Lair in eastern Germany.
The same thing applies for the British night bombers. Indeed, one of the reason the British chose the strategy of night bombing was that it was too costly to attack by day compared to the benefit of precise targeting, because the bombing was not precise in the end.
So, I don't know if the Allies knew about the Wolf's Lair, if they knew approximately or precisely its location. But even if the last (precise location) was know by them, mounting a bombing raid would have been a huge operation (many bombers to cover an area large enough to bomb the Wolf's Lair and its surroundings) comparable to the raids on Berlin or other German large cities, for a doubting result: the Allies would have had to be sure if Hitler was there during the raid, if he was not protected in a bunker, etc...
As a (very very) side note, but it illustrates my words, consider nowadays how the killing by bombing of the chief of Hezbollah is considered as a difficult operation, and you could imagine how unreachable it was during WWII.

If you think of US bombers as flying with their navigators blindfolded, you will not be that far off -- navigation was a combination of dead reckoning and trying to spot landmarks on the ground -- hard to do from high altitude especially with few highways to follow. (And the US had it easy -- British were flying at night.) Even if they could reach modern-day Poland (I don't think they had the range), they'd be lucky to drop their bombs within fifty miles of the target.

Also if you look at the map, it is very, very far East.   The various bomber forces could not have expected a fighter escort until early 1944 at best. The Germans had radar, so a quick dip by Hitler into a bunker would have been expected, making the whole thing very very pointless.

This answer assumes that the goal of bombing the Wolf's Lair would be to kill Hitler. I see many other possible motivations : to disorganize the German's chain of command, to force the Germans to place more anti-aircraft capabilities in that area (thus removing them from more strategic locations), to exacerbate Hitler's paranoia to induce him to take irrational decisions detrimental to Germany's war effort, to lower German High Command's morale...

@ItalianPhilosopher Seeing speculation on why they didn't do it is interesting, though I'd be even more interested in the actual historical reasoning if there was any

@Evargalo Do you have any idea how costly long range bomb raids like Regensburg were?  They had a very specific goal in mind, not your fuzzy "let's mess with them", to destroy a critical link in the Luftwaffe's supply chain.  Didn't work, but at least there was some logic.  There isn't in yours.  How succesfull were the Blitz raids in 1940 over London,  Churchill HQ, to achieve exactly the type of goals you advocate? Not very, if at all.  It's not by itself a bad question, but once you know the specifics, it wouldn't make any sense whatsoever.

@MarkOlson I think you're taking it a bit too hard: it was a difficult task but they became pretty good at. The British used radio based navigation (don't know if the Americans used as well). And from Italy and to a less extent UK, they reached as far as Warsaw (even if they could not drop in corect zones)

@Evargalo Do you have sources for the Allies believing, during the war, that Hitler would make bad decisions because of one or two raids?

Also, actually killing Hitler before 1945 would be disastrous for the allies as it's highly likely somebody competent would take over.

@totalMongot For most targets if you are not dropping the payload in the correct zone you have failed your mission - and bunkers like these usually need to be hit directly, missing even by 50 meters would not be enough. Also consider that even late in WW2 there are multiple cases of bombers missing their targets by hundreds of kilometers - for example, on March 4, 1945, a group of bombers hit Zürich instead of their target, which was almost 300 kilometers north. I'd say they got "better", but not quite "good".

@ItalianPhilosopher : the cost-benefit analysis in your comment could be part of a good answer, but my remark remains : the goal of such a raid (if it was practicable, and it probably wasn't) might have been to kill Hitler but it might also have been something different.

@Joshua : Hitler's death would have generated uncertain consequences. "Somebody competent taking over" is one possibility (but after 1943, wouldn't "somebody competent" sue for peace ?), but a leadership crisis, a fight between several would-be Führers, or a schism between the army and the civilian power are other possibilities. Admittedly, Allies were not willing to gamble on that...

@Evargalo You think I am peddling accounting-talk when I say "costly"?  No, those early unescorted raids were a butchery of men.  It was literally throwing lives away.

@ItalianPhilosopher : I said nothing of the sort, and I a well aware that WWII was a butchery of men and that it was literally throwing lives away.

It isn’t known
The Soviets didn’t know about it until they got there on the ground. The Western Allies have never released any information indicating whether they knew or not.
What is known, is that the facility never came under air attack. Whether that’s because they didn’t know about it or knew and didn’t attack for reasons (see below), we just don’t know.
Reasons for not attacking
It’s a tiny target in a very big forest. Allied airforces before 1944 were doing ok if they could find the right city, let alone finding what amounted to a scout camp in the wilderness.
It’s a long way to East Prussia. Berlin was a long way from England and East Prussia is as far away again.
Killing Hitler stopped being a priority for the Allies by the middle of 1944. By then, they had decided that his continued command over Germany was helping them more than it helped the Germans. There were plans drawn up for a suicide mission to assassinate Hitler at the Berghof that were known and approved of (the planning was approved that is) at the PM's level. However, they were never given the green light.

Interesting about the better-keep Hitler aspect.  I mean, he was a kind of anti-Midas and did turn a lot of military planning into sh*t by Stalingrad and up.  Do you have sources for that however?

@ItalianPhilosopher https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1998/07/24/british-spies-planned-many-deaths-for-hitler/81cc958c-f5ee-4bb1-9f50-a40c74302331/

The ”Wolf’s Lair” was some 60 miles SE of Kaliningrad, camouflaged in a heavily wooded area.
Any strike by heavy bombers would have to come from eastern Great Britian, most probably from somewhere in East Anglia.  Looking at three potential locations, we can easily work out the average distance from these to the vicinity of Kaliningrad:
From Southend (about 40 mi east of London) to Kaliningrad, the great circle distance is roughly 888 miles; from Stansfield (about 40 mi NNE of London) to Kaliningrad, about 864 miles; and from Norwich to Kaliningrad, about 803 miles.  Average these and we get approximately 852 miles.
All one way, and, again by a great circle route.  Easy for a modern airliner, but not so much for a mid-1944 heavy bomber formation under wartime conditions.
And great circle routes in 1944 were rarely, if ever, used.  Navigation was by known ground way points, complicated by avoidance of known concentrations of defensive AAA locations and proximity to fighter interception fields.  Such maneuvering easily adds 100 miles, one way, to the distance any strike would have to travel, not to mention the effects of AAA fire and interceptors on any bomber formation or stream.  Any mission would also be well beyond any support from escorting fighters, so the bombers would pretty much be on their own.
So, figure about a minimum of 950 miles one way, 1900 miles round trip, to strike a target area without specifically located targets hiding in a forest.
Was it even doable? Well . . .
With typical configurations, a B-17G carrying 6000 lbs of bombs had a round trip range of about 1100 miles.  B-24s had the same problem, with 8000 lbs of bombs, a round trip range of 1600 miles.  And a Lancaster, with 14000 lbs of bombs could count on about 1660 mile round trip range.  So all of the major bomb haulers of the day were out of contention unless some commander was prepared to lose the entire strike flight.
Of course one could reduce the bomb load to squeeze out a few more miles or, even, with some difficulty, configure for extra fuel, but probably still not enough to make the round trip.  And the reality was the real downside to squeeze extra miles meant serious, yea, major, reductions in ordnance delivery.
So, even if changes in configuration could allow for a mission – and the only possibility for such a mission would be the Lancaster, exactly what would be the point, considering Bomber Command’s penchant for only night operations, of scattering very limited ordnance about the general vicinity of a forest in the dark?  All you have to do is look at the dispersal of ordnance about existing targets whether by day or night, as opposed to actual target hits to realize the exercise in futility.
And some concept of shuttle bombing to Soviet controlled fields such as Operation Frantic?  Well it does not take much effort to see how well that worked out.  An interesting concept that was ultimately unworkable for a variety of reasons.  See.
Bottom line was such a mission, or missions, were not technically or practically feasible.

Since your answer revolves largely around the question of range, you might be interested in this graphic, showing that even with the P-51 with drop tanks, the bombers would be unescorted for 1/3 of the inbound and all the outbound leg (with the Luftwaffe being well aware that they would be comming, probably low on ammo themselves while the Luftwaffe fighters would be rearmed & refueled). A mascacre waiting to happen. https://i.sstatic.net/2fHvzLZM.jpg

Kind of a "you want us to what?  Where?  How far? With what?  Uh huh.

I may be remembering a different site, but I recall that RAF 617 squadron (the Dam Busters) did perform an operation to attack a known countryside retreat used by Hitler. Only on arrival did they discover it was sufficiently well hidden they couldn't find it - so they diverted to a nearby Gestapo barracks. This is one of many incidents recorded in 'The Dam Busters', the wartime history of the squadron by Paul Brickhill.
It should be remembered that 617 squadron was a specialist precision bombing unit. Their wartime record includes things like direct hits on a major railway bridge three times out of three (one bomb landed each end of the bridge, lifting it off its foundations, and then a third passed through the bridgedeck), a deliberate policy when bombing bridges of sending in a flight at a time and returning home with the remaining bombs if they had destroyed the target (they never had to send in the second flight), bombing an L-shaped factory without damaging the cafeteria building in the corner of the L (it was in occupied France - Churchill personally threatened to disband the squadron if any Frenchman was injured), and dive-bombing in Lancasters (it was the best way to place target markers until they were given a couple of Mosquitoes for the purpose). It's also worth noting that they had the Tallboy (and later Grand Slam) 'earthquake' bombs, specifically designed for destroying building foundations and ideal for bunkers (they were designed to hit the ground at supersonic speeds and bury themselves before detonating).
As others have noted, the ordinary heavy bombing techniques of the period were only suitable for area bombing, and the conventional thin-case bombs were ineffective against bunkers and similarly solid structures because their blast dissipated rapidly in air. The RAF commonly used Mosquitoes for precision bombing, but those could not carry a heavy enough load for large targets or bunkers.

The 'Wolfschanze' was over a 1000 km (by road) further east from the Möhnetalsperre (where the 'Dam Busters' performed their major successes).

And they would have still had to have launched from Great Britain with all the same attendant problems and limitations.
